# As an Undergraduate student can Join at conference with Full research paper?

Tags: paper-submission, research-undergraduate

I am Hasnain Imtiaz Sakib. Under graduate student (2nd year) from University of Dhaka. I have been selected and my abstract has been selected for "6th World media and mass communication conference 2020" at University of Cagliari. As an undergraduate student will it be a lucrative project for me? I need some valuable suggestion from you that can help me very much. Even as an undergraduate student, it is going to challenging for me to do. Should I have to attend a conference with a full paper? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. If an abstract has been accepted it may not mean that the paper has been accepted. That would probably be a separate process. Have you been told you will make a presentation? For an abstract it might be very short, or even a poster only. The conference program committee is the place where you can learn these things, though they should be on the web site.

Comment: At one conference, My abstract paper and Proposal has been selected, they have a good number of publications, prominent key speakers, they arranged 
 a good number of conferences (Thiland,Malaysia,Bangladesh,India,China,Indonesia, Srilanka etc). But my problem is as an undergrad student, should I have to join these kind of conference and is there any possibility to write up for an international journal as a junior student!

Comment: That doesn't help me understand your question, sorry. Selected for what, exactly? And is the abstract different from the full  paper? In the title you mention "Full research paper". In the body you mention only "abstract".

Comment: Please proceed with caution.  You have no evidence that the listed speakers will attend.  The past conferences could be terrible conferences.  Ask someone in your field if this is a conference worth the cost of attending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having a low tier publication as an undergraduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/having-a-low-tier-publication-as-an-undergraduate-student)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have discussed this with your advisor and figured a way to pay for the airfare *before* you submitted an abstract to the conference. What makes you think this is a good conference?

I have no idea if this is a valid conference or not.  Perhaps another answer will tell you.  Have you already paid the registration fee?  If not, please wait.  There are conferences out there that just want your registration fee, and make a nice excuse for a vacation.

Comment: But they have a good number of publication(TIIKM-The International Institute of Knowledge and management), they have prominent key speakers, ISSN numbers, institutions ranks are really good. This is my first time and I don't have any Idea, even feeling too much inferior as an undergrad student. I need help badly. Need some suggestion. I have got acceptance letter, reviewers comments and other stuffs in a good manner.

Comment: You need someone in our area, not random academics.  I am a mathematician and have no idea about this conference.  Perhaps it is legitimate.  It sounds like you are not getting any assistance from your university.  Who assisted you in the research that lead to your abstract?

Comment: "A good number of publications" is not the same thing as "good publications", and  "a good number of conferences" is not the same thing as "good conferences".  Not even close.  Anyone can buy an ISSN.  Scam conferences regularly list people from highly ranked universities who have no relationship with the conference.  **The only way to tell whether the conference is good is to ask people with experience in the field.**  Ask your local faculty.