# Preparing for Higher education/Self-teaching

Tags: research-process, undergraduate, preparation

I am currently a 2nd year undergraduate student studying Business/Finance/Information Systems at a decent, normal university.  I have amazing grades and general interests in pursuing higher education or conducting my own research in some way.

While my current standing in knowledge is still relatively minute, I'm extremely interested in certain fields -- such as econometrics, financial theory, etc -- that I learn on my own time.  Many of my peers find classes and course material frustrating but I get a tinge of excitement everytime I'm able to understand and articulate on a certain concept being taught.  This is especially true in Mathematics as I have a strong math background compared to my students in my degree but meagre in comparison to the material I am trying to learn.

People currently in Academia or pursuing Academia, what are some of your recommendations in preparing for higher education or just learning more on my spare time.  Currently I am taking some online coursera courses and reading a few books I've found through the library.  What other sources should I be considering?  When is a good to start reading journal articles/papers?

Comment: Have you seen [I am a 2nd year undergraduate student. What should I do now to prepare for my PhD?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/i-am-a-2nd-year-undergraduate-student-what-should-i-do-now-to-prepare-for-my-ph)? If your question is different, can you explain how?

Comment: This didn't come up on my first search.  Thanks for the link!  While his situation is similar to mine and the responses did answer most of my questions, I still want to ask for any recommendations on academic resources (with specifics to economics, finance, statistics, etc) that I might not be aware of currently.

Comment: What kind of "academic resources" were you thinking of? Recommendations of individual books, papers, etc would be considered off topic here.